# Getting JVM error after SOAP UI installation

Tags: java, jvm, soapui

I am trying to install `SOAPUI` tool. After the installation, when executed, I amm getting this error:

> The JVM could not be started. The maximum heap size (-XMx) might be
>   too large or anti virus or firewall tool could block the execution

When installed to a different machine, it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error often occurs if you try to set too much memory on a 32-bit OS such as Windows. E.g. if you use `-Xmx1600m` or more on Windows 32-bit you will get this error.

Which OS and version of Java do you have on the machine which fails.

Comment: Windows XP has a particularly low limit for maximum heap size. Its can be as low as 1.2 GB.

Comment: Within soapUI-4.5.1.vmoptions file in "bin" directory, I reduced the xmx from 1200m (default) to 486m and that makes it to work

Comment: If, like me, you don't know where set the memory value see [ankit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16331731/224976)

Answer (score 20):

This problem occurs because Soap Ui tries to get the specified amount of memory in form of single block which is rarely available. 
So solution to this problem is navigate to soapUi.x.x.x.vmoption file which can be found in

c->program files-> emiware -> soapUi.x.x.x ->bin

edit this file and make the -Xms to something lesser default value is 1200m make it 512m if does not work change it some to a lesser value.

**PS x.x.x. is the version of SoapUI in my case its 4.0.0**

-Xms means initial heap size.

-Xmx means maximum heap size.

So you can set values as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What I did with mine is kill all application processes that use Java, for example: Mozilla FireFox. You can kill the process from Windows Task Manager. After that, rerun your SOAP UI.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a simple fix to this soapUI issue...

Ankit and Peter have mentioned about it here... to help you (and others) with this, I have written a step-by-step tutorial for this along with screenshots for the fix. I hope this helps you...!

You can check it here - http://quicksoftwaretesting.com/soapui-jvm-heap-size-xmx-error/

Comment: you should rather post the solution here instead of giving the link.

Comment: To summarize Amandeep's solution, edit the SoapUi-5.0.0.vmoptions file (which exists in the SoapUI bin folder), modify the line -Xmx1000m and reduce the memory usage. I changed from 1000m to 512m with success.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these solutions worked for me. What did work was starting the soapui.bat file int he same mentioned \bin directory.
This file does set the required JAVA environment settings.

Using Java a lot I cannot do this as an general Environment variable since this will impact my SQLdeveloper from Oracle and other Java goodies.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you downloaded the appropriate version (32/64 bit) for your OS.